# get the recent file

Tags: pnp-powershell

I am logging into the sharepoint webiste and getting folder contents as follows:

```
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteName -Credential $credential -ReturnConnection

$wholeContent = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $filePath -ItemType File -Connection $connection

$Library =  $wholeContent | where { $_.Name -match "^Amma\s{1}\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.zip$" }

Write-Output $Library
```

The output has the following format

### Name          #          Type    #       Items/Size       #        Last Modified

with a list of files from which I want get the most recent file. As you have noticed from the above snippet that I used the regular expression on the "Name" attribute by $_.Name. How do I address the attribute "Last Modified" if I have to get the most recent file based on the attribute "Last Modified" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, I have added the sort object

$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteName -Credential $credential -ReturnConnection

$wholeContent = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $filePath -ItemType File -Connection $connection

$Library =  $wholeContent | where { $_.Name -match "^Amma\s{1}\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.zip$" } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -Last 1

Write-Output $Library

Comment: $Library = $wholeContent | where { $_.Name -match "^Amma\s{1}\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.zip$" } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -Last 1 is the one that worked for me